# Integrate opensips with MSRP Rely?

Tags: sip, opensips

I have opensips server setup.I want to add  MSRP capabilities in it .I have googled it for more than two hours and found only that I can  use sylk server for this because it has built in MSRP Relay and I can forward my invite request  to sylk server .I want to know how can I achieve this .Or any other method for opensips and MSRP relay integration.

Answer (score 0):

AG Projects also offer a stand-alone version of [MSRP Relay](http://www.msrprelay.org/). You could try to integrate it with your existing OpenSIPS setup.